# Docker installation

Tags: linux, docker

I know there are 2 ways to install `docker` on `rhel7` : by repo and by packages. I tried installing through repo using link 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/rhel/#install-docker-ee
But during command:   `sudo yum makecache fast`    I am getting error

```
File contains no section header
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ee.repo, line 1
'<!doctype html>'
```

And I don't know how to install through packages 
So please tell me one way

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install last Docker Engine version is using official installation script of Docker.

To do this, you only have to execute this command, which will retrieve and execute the script.

`wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

```
yum update
```

Put the following text in /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo

```
[dockerrepo] 
name=Docker Repository 
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/ 
enabled=1 
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
```

Now run the following commands to update the repo and install docker

```
yum clean all
yum repolist all
yum install docker-engine –y
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See:  [What signifies “Good” self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)